# Angular Animations 1.3 -> 1.4

Tags: angularjs, animation

I just recently migrated from Angular 1.3 to 1.4.7 and I knew there were going to be breaking changes regarding animations, but I'm stuck as to how to fix them. Here is a small summary of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a dialog with 5 steps (kind of like a form registration). When a user hits "next", the current and next page should animate right-to-left, as such:

```
          [VIEWPORT]

        <---Page 1  <--- Page 2
```

Vice-versa for when the user hits "back". So the way I accomplished this was by using Angular's enter/leave animation functionality to add a class to the page div which would trigger CSS animations. Here is the Javascript that added either "on-next" or "on-back" to the div that was leaving and the div that was entering.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc animation
 * @name AnimateWizard
 * @description
 * Animation for a wizard when moving to the next/previous page.
 */
angular.module('wizard.common').animation('.animate-wizard', ['AnimatedWizardService', function(wizardService) {
    var animate = function(element) {
        //reset the element's animation classes first since there can be leftovers from previous animations
        wizardService.removeAnimations(element);
        wizardService.addAnimation(element);
    };

    return {
        enter: enter,
        leave: leave
    };

    function enter(element, done) {
        animate(element);
        done();
    }

    function leave(element, done) {
        animate(element);
        done();
    }
}]);
/**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name AnimatedWizardService
 * @description
 * Stores the class that is required to animate a wizard's steps.
 */
angular.module('wizard.common').service('AnimatedWizardService', function() {
    var _animationClass;
    var validAnimationClasses = ['on-next', 'on-back'];

    return {
        //Controller calls this when the user hits "next" or "back"
        //`klass` can be "on-next" or "on-back" depending on which way we want to animate the pages
        setClass : function(klass) {
            if(validAnimationClasses.indexOf(klass) !== -1) {
                _animationClass = klass;
            } else {
                //Developer error - fail hard!
                throw new Error(klass + ' is not a valid animation.');
            }
        },
        addAnimation : function(element) {
            angular.element(element).addClass(_animationClass);
        },
        removeAnimations : function(element) {
            angular.element(element).removeClass(validAnimationClasses.join(' '));
        }
    };
});
})();
```

Here is the CSS

```
.animate-wizard {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.animate-wizard.ng-enter {
    will-change: transform;
    -webkit-animation: wizardPageOnNextEnter 500ms ease both;
    -moz-animation: wizardPageOnNextEnter 500ms ease both;
    animation: wizardPageOnNextEnter 500ms ease both;

    &.on-next {
        -webkit-animation: wizardPageOnNextEnter 500ms ease both;
        -moz-animation: wizardPageOnNextEnter 500ms ease both;
        animation: wizardPageOnNextEnter 500ms ease both;
    }

    &.on-back {
        -webkit-animation: wizardPageOnBackEnter 500ms ease both;
        -moz-animation: wizardPageOnBackEnter 500ms ease both;
        animation: wizardPageOnBackEnter 500ms ease both;
    }
}

.animate-wizard.ng-leave {
    will-change: transform;
    -webkit-animation: wizardPageOnNextLeave 500ms ease both;
    -moz-animation: wizardPageOnNextLeave 500ms ease both;
    animation: wizardPageOnNextLeave 500ms ease both;

    &.on-next {
        -webkit-animation: wizardPageOnNextLeave 500ms ease both;
        -moz-animation: wizardPageOnNextLeave 500ms ease both;
        animation: wizardPageOnNextLeave 500ms ease both;
    }

    &.on-back {
        -webkit-animation: wizardPageOnBackLeave 500ms ease both;
        -moz-animation: wizardPageOnBackLeave 500ms ease both;
        animation: wizardPageOnBackLeave 500ms ease both;
    }
}

//Page 1 leaving to the left
@keyframes wizardPageOnNextLeave {
    from{} to{ -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes wizardPageOnNextLeave {
    from{} to{ -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes wizardPageOnNextLeave {
    from{} to{ -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
//Page 2 entering from the right
@keyframes wizardPageOnNextEnter {
    from{ -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); -moz-transform: translateX(100%); transform: translateX(100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes wizardPageOnNextEnter {
    from{ -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes wizardPageOnNextEnter {
    from{ -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
}
//Page 2 leaving to the right
@keyframes wizardPageOnBackLeave {
    from{} to{ -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); -moz-transform: translateX(100%); transform: translateX(100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes wizardPageOnBackLeave {
    from{} to{ -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes wizardPageOnBackLeave {
    from{} to{ -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
}
//Page 1 entering from the left
@keyframes wizardPageOnBackEnter {
    from{ -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes wizardPageOnBackEnter {
    from{ -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes wizardPageOnBackEnter {
    from{ -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

Lastly, here is some sample HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="animate-wizard" ng-if="currentStep === 1">
    <div class="animate-wizard" ng-if="currentStep === 2">
    <div class="animate-wizard" ng-if="currentStep === 3">
    <div class="animate-wizard" ng-if="currentStep === 4">
</div>
```

This all worked, but now I'm not sure what to change / if I should just start over. I've seen examples of angular wizard forms, but most of them just animate one way. Any ideas would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! So the problem was that "ng-enter" was never being added to the div during its animation. I needed to do this:

```
return {
    enter : function(element, done) {
        $animateCss(element, {
            event: 'ng-enter'
        }).start().done(done);
    },
    leave ....
}
```

and obviously 'ng-leave' for the leave event. Works like a charm!